# Flask works when running via Python but not working when running via command line

Tags: python, flask

I have a folder structure as this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── logger.py
├── main.py
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   └── uom.py
├── requirements.txt
├── routes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   └── uom.py
├── services
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── uom.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── misc.py
│       └── templates.py
└── swagger.yaml
```

Within `main.py`, I have imports like the following:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_smorest import Api

from logger import setup_logger
from routes import all_routes
```

Note that `logger.py` is on the same directory as `main.py`, and `all_routes` live in `routes.__init__.py`. If I run `python main.py` at this directory level, everything would run fine, but if I run `flask` on command line, I would encounter this error:

```
Error: While importing 'api_v2.main', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/REPO/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 219, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/REPO/api_v2/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from logger import setup_logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logger'
```

I'm not that familiar with Flask under the hood, and generally when deployed, not using command line would be fine. But I'd still like to understand how this is happening. It seems like `flask` command is importing `main.py` but not the rest of the directory?

I've already made sure:

- I'm running the same virtual environment (`poetry shell` specifically, and both `flask` and `flask-smorest` are added via poetry)
- Change the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to `main.py`

Comment: what is this api_v2 directory? are you running flask one directory higher? specifically what is the flask run command you use?

Comment: @Matthias I'm running flask in `api_v2`, which is the root directory of what I posted with `tree`. Even a simple `flask` would return such error with help messages on options available.

Comment: did you try not exporting `FLASK_APP` or exporting it to be the `api_v2` directory instead of main.py? as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330083/how-can-i-run-a-flask-app-from-outside-the-top-level-directory

Comment: because the error message indicates that you are running Flask from the wrong directory, it's trying to import api_v2.main which it should not be.. unless you have `import api_v2.main` in your file? in which case you have to run Flask in the directory above `api_v2`

Comment: @Matthias Thank you for the response. `import api_v2.main` is not in the code, and I have tried `export FLASK_APP=api_v2` before, which would become: `Error: Could not import 'api_v2.api_v2'`. Or `export FLASK_APP=api_v2.main`, would become: `Error: Could not import 'api_v2.api_v2.main'`. I suspect it's because instead of having `main.py` at repo root, I have it under `api_v2`, but it's  going to require some reconstruction if I were to migrate everything a directory level up

Comment: wait no you have to put the full path in FLASK_APP, I would try that, `/home/whatever/.../api_v2`

Comment: full path might work, relative path should also work, but for some reason, seems you have it coded somewhere in some environment that flask runs from that api_v2 or has that programmed somewhere, that's why a full path might work here

Comment: @Matthias I just wanted to say I appreciate your help. We have decided to move on to TypeScript, so this project is going stale. I did try full path, but wasn't really working, so likely something I didn't do right environment wise. You're great for trying to help though!